# Pass filename to shell script

Tags: ubuntu, shell

On Windows, I can drag and drop a file to a batch file to pass the filename. On Ubuntu 12.10, I can't drag and drop to an `.sh` file.

Opening terminal and running

```
./sh-file-name.sh file-name.txt
```

works, but it takes some time.

Is there any other way to send a filename easily?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gnome, you may want to check out

https://askubuntu.com/questions/52789/drag-and-drop-file-onto-script-in-nautilus

Comment: Can you please explain how this answers the question?

Comment: the question is very similar to the one asked by the user. fixed link.